# How to Create MY_Controller in Yii2

Tags: yii

I'm newbie in Yii, especially Yii2. How can I create MY_Controller like CI in YII2 ? so other controllers will `extend` to MY_Controller.

Comment: This is a good place to start http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-overview.html

Comment: The controllers: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html

Comment: Thank you @Michael, I'll read the documentation deeply, this is because I'm first in Yii and maybe confusing migration from CI :)

Comment: It's kind of spammy if you don't read the documentation first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in YII2, called as BaseController. I think in another framework have same name `BaseController` .

First, if you're using basic template, create BaseController.php inside component directory.

```
namespace app\components;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\helpers\Url;

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }
    public function _anotherMethod(){ /* your code goes here */ }

}
```

Next in your other controllers :

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use app\components\BaseController;

class YourController extends BaseController
{
  public function init()
  {
    parent::init();
  }
  public function _anotherAction()
  {
    // your code
  }
}
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you. You save my life :) @Hendra

Comment: You are welcome :) , but next time please search before ask, because the same question is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461417/how-can-create-basecontroller-extends-controller-in-yii-2).